# Get IST time in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

if (minutes < 10)
minutes = "0" + minutes

document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b>")
//-->
</script>
```

Getting local comupter time.
I want to get IST time in javascript.

Comment: You only have access to the clientside computers clock, what are you expecting to get ?

Comment: You'll have to convert the local time to UTC and then add the offset for ITC

Comment: I dont know how to do that please give me example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EU249/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The following will allow you to convert local time to IST time:

```
var currentTime = new Date();

var currentOffset = currentTime.getTimezoneOffset();

var ISTOffset = 330;   // IST offset UTC +5:30 

var ISTTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + (ISTOffset + currentOffset)*60000);

// ISTTime now represents the time in IST coordinates

var hoursIST = ISTTime.getHours()
var minutesIST = ISTTime.getMinutes()

document.write("<b>" + hoursIST + ":" + minutesIST + " " + "</b>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. For all other supported time zones, you can check this array:
`Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')`

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const date = new Date();
  const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() == 0 ? 0 : -1 * date.getTimezoneOffset();

  let normalized = new Date(date.getTime() + (offset) * 60000);
  let indiaTime = new Date(normalized.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Calcutta"}));

  // console.log(`Time in India:: ${indiaTime.toISOString()}`);
  demo.innerHTML = indiaTime.toISOString();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<body style="padding:20px; font-family: monospace; font-size: 16px;">
  <div>
    Time in India: <span id="demo">loading...</span>
  </div>
</body>
```