# Getting standard IST time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to get current Standard IST time but I am getting system time only using below function.

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentOffset = currentTime.getTimezoneOffset();
var ISTOffset = 330;
var d1 = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + (ISTOffset + currentOffset)*60000);
```

Is there any api or library that helps me in getting standard IST time.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get IST time in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134726/get-ist-time-in-javascript)

Comment: yeah, why not to use moment.js : http://momentjs.com/

Comment: What is your system timezone set to

Comment: Tried moment.js but its still getting system time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java script currently doesn't helps to get current time, I have finally used the timestamp in my response headers in service calls

Answer (score 0):

You could use `moment.js`, a standard utility to handle all time and date related functions. You simple import [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and for your desired use case implement a method such as

`moment().utcOffset("+05:30").format()`

for setting the the time in IST which is +05:30 from GMT.

Comment: Tried using monemt and moment-timezone bower libs, but moment().utcOffset("+05:30").format() still returning me system time. Tried this also moment().tz("Asia/Calcutta").toISOString(); but still system time is effecting

Comment: This is from an answer that I previously looked up when I had the same problem. You can checkout [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355297/how-to-add-ist-timezone-object-to-moment-js]. Try all possible solutions to see if anything works for you.

Comment: Finally resolved it by using the timestamp in response headers in my service calls