# Fri May 29 2020 06:35:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) i want India Standard Time as IST in react js

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

i want to get timezone name like **India Standard Time** as **IST** from **Fri May 29 2020 06:35:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22134810/8885880

Answer (score 0):

```js
moment().tz('Asia/Colombo').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a Z[(IST)]');
```

You can format IST using moment JS timezones. https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Comment: i want time zone name like **India Standard Time** from given date

Comment: I assume you need zone out of the date. What is the input format you would like to extract zone ?

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy , new Date() gives different results based on browsers timezone, keeping that in mind why should we hard code `tz('Asia/Colombo')` . If app has users from different locations hard coding is not gonna work.